# html-validator module with typescript es6 import syntax

Tags: typescript, validation, npm, ecmascript-6

I would like to import [html-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-validator) module with es6 syntax.

```
import validator from 'html-validator';
```

I am getting this error:

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'html-validator'. '.../node_modules/html-validator/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.   Try `npm install @types/html-validator` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'html-validator';`

So `@types/html-validator` doesn't exist.

I've declared module inside `.ds.ts` file:

```
declare module 'html-validator' {
  export =  validator;
}
```

And I am getting another error:

> Invalid module name in augmentation. Module 'html-validator' resolves to an untyped module at '.../node_modules/html-validator/index.js', which cannot be augmented

This is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es6","dom"],
    "outDir": "build",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}
```

This works fine.

```
 const validator = require('html-validator');
```

But I would prefer es6 version

Answer (score 0):

As of I know, I could not see any package like `@types/html-validator` at `npm`.

So, we ourselves have to declare the typings for it.

Even the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-validator) for the `html-validator` imports the same way like below as you did.

```
const validator = require('html-validator');
```

Comment: I know that `@types/html-validator` package doesn't exist. I've mentioned it. And I know that inside docs it was used with older version of import. I just want to be sure there is no another solution.

Answer (score 0):

May be one of those will work for you:

```
import { validator } from "html-validator";
```

or

```
import { html-validator } from "html-validator";
```

Comment: And this doesn't work as well
`import * as validator from "html-validator"`